# Get the commit ID of the last tag in git history

Tags: git, git-commit

I am on a commit which is not tagged. But there are tags in the commit history. So, following command gives me the latest release tag from the history

```
git describe --abbrev=0 --tags
```

Above outputs the tag like `1.15.21` which is good.
How can I get the commit ID that this tag was created on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `git rev-parse` to get the commit corresponding to a branch/tag

```
git rev-parse HEAD
abc123......
```

So you can then pipe the output of your `git describe` using `xargs`

```
git describe --abbrev=0 --tags | xargs git rev-parse
def456.....
```

Comment: Are you sure `xargs git rev-parse` gets the commit at the release tag?

Comment: @TheWaterProgrammer Yes that is correct. You can convince yourself of that by running `git rev-parse 1.15.21` or `git log -1 1.15.21` and comparing that commit ID to the one produced by piping with `xargs`